# Post Model is always empty

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, post

I have 2 pages. On first i only have form to post data for search, On second i also have the same form for search and container with search result. When i made post from First form - Model to Search Method came as what i expected but from Second Form Model Properties is setted as default values ( int - 0, bool - false, string - null, etc.)

What is the problem?

---

First Fom :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")" method="POST">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Search</legend>

        <!-- Search input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CertID">Certificate ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="CertID" name="CertID" type="search" placeholder="Certificate ID" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Search input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CertAuthCode">Certificate AuthCode</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="CertAuthCode" name="CertAuthCode" type="search" placeholder="Certificate AuthCode" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="IncludePreviousQuestionnaire" value="true"> Include Previous Questionnaire?
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="searchCert"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="searchCert" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
```

Second Form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")" method="POST">
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Search</legend>

    <!-- Search input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchCertRequest.CertID, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        @*<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CertID">Certificate ID</label>*@
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchCertRequest.CertID, new { @placeholder = "Certificate ID", @class = "form-control input-md", @required="required" })
            @*<input id="CertID" name="SearchCertRequest.CertID" type="search" placeholder="Certificate ID" class="form-control input-md" required="">*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchCertRequest.CertID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Search input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchCertRequest.CertAuthCode, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        @*<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CertAuthCode">Certificate AuthCode</label>*@
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchCertRequest.CertAuthCode, new { @placeholder = "Certificate AuthCode", @class = "form-control input-md", @required = "required" })
            @*<input id="CertAuthCode" name="SearchCertRequest.CertAuthCode" type="search" placeholder="Certificate AuthCode" class="form-control input-md" required="">*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchCertRequest.CertAuthCode)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.SearchCertRequest.IncludePreviousQuestionnaire)
                    @*<input type="checkbox" name="SearchCertRequest.IncludePreviousQuestionnaire">*@ Include Previous Questionnaire?
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="searchCertBtn"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="searchCertBtn" name="searchCertBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Model for Search Request:

```
 public class SearchCertRequest
{
    [Required]
    public long CertID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CertAuthCode { get; set; }
    public bool IncludePreviousQuestionnaire { get; set; }
}
```

Update : Model For 2nd Form exists in next one:

```
public class SearchViewModel
    {
        public SearchCertModel CertModel { get; set; } // Serch Result
        public SearchCertRequest SearchCertRequest { get; set; } // Search Request
    }
```

---

**RESOLVED** : I made Partial View from Search Forms and now it's working. Can somebody explain why? Thanks.

Comment: What is your model for the second form? (its a class that contains a property `SearchCertRequest`) so your post method parameter should be that model, not `SearchCertRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms are posting back to the same method (Search method of Home controller).As the first is working the signature must be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult (SearchCertRequest model)
{
```

but the second form is generating controls for `SearchViewModel` so the signature would have to be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult (SearchViewModel model)
{
```

**Edit**

To explain the comment in your edit. With the second form your generating controls such as `<input  name="SearchCertRequest.CertID" ...>`. When you create a partial view and pass it the `SearchCertRequest` property of `SearchViewModel`, then it will generate controls such as `<input  name="CertID" ...>` which will correctly post back to `public ActionResult (SearchCertRequest model)`

Comment: maybe i didn't understand your comment. This make sense, Thank you.